# Use Table without messing with DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to make a table having cells bound to several objects (for example, textboxes) without making use of DataGrid?

Comment: Please try and ask a more concrete question. I'm sure the answer is "yes" but is that all you wanted to ask? Is that really going to help you achieve what you want?

Comment: @jberger, There is no GridView in WPF.

Comment: [`ListView` has a mode called `GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747048.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" Width="300"></TextBox>
```

The DataContext for the textbox's container should contain a Property named `FileName`

You should note that your property should be wired to notify when it is changed.  See the following for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: this has nothing to do with a "Table"